# How do you show list length in StringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I want to show the number of search results that are going to appear in the table, is there a way to show the number of elements or do you have to compute it, ie I want to show something like this:

```
Found $results.size$ result$if(rest(contacts))$s$endif$.
```

The "s" correctly shows when there is more than one search result, but the `$results.size$` returns nothing. Not sure if it matters, but im using Java, so its a List thats being passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, there is a length() function, ie:

```
Found $length(results)$ result$if(rest(contacts))$s$endif$.
```